# What would be a reliable way to get fractional value from a number?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a number of type `Decimal(8, 2)` and have been using `Substring` to get fractional value.

```
E.g.)
    declare @val decimal(8, 2), @strVal varchar(10)
    set @val = 15.80
    set @strVal = cast(@val as varchar)
    select  @val, substring(@strVal, charindex('.', @strVal), len(@strVal))
```

**Is there a better way to simply get fractional value, `.80` from `@val` without having to convert it to a character?** 
I am wondering if there is a built-in UDF (User-Defined Function) that would parse instead of having to rolling out my own version.

Comment: Your question makes no sense.  you have a decimal and you're trying to convert it to a decimal????

Comment: What ??!  You already have the decimal value, in @val.  What the substring is doing is retreiving the fractional value as a character value.

Comment: Yes, fractional value of type `int` is what I am trying to get out of it. So from 15.80, I would like to get `.80`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the modulus (%) operator. You'll get `0.80`.

Like this:

```
declare @val decimal(8, 2)
set     @val = 15.80
select  @val, @val % 1
```

Comment: Ha, expected nothing less from a guy with a handle, `md5sum`. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure why people continuously overlook the modulus operator... I've seen some REALLY bizarre ways of stripping whole numbers off of decimal values.

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean the fractional value, not the decimal value. You already have teh decimal value.  To get the fractional value, use [Round](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238494(SQL.80).aspx), or [Floor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178531.aspx) functions

```
  Declare @Fraction Decimal(8,2)
  Set @Fraction = @Val - Floor(@Val)
```

or

```
  Set @Fraction = @Val - Round(@Val, 0)
```

Comment: I haven't explored *mathematical* functions, yet and this looks like a simply but yet reliable way to get a fractional number.  Thanks Charles.

Comment: No problem,   check out the Round, and the floor reference links, to see how they work and the diofferences between them...

Answer (score 1):

```
SET @val = (@val - ROUND(@val, 0, 1) * 100)
```

The ROUND(@val, 0, 1) should truncate the 15.80 into a 15.00. Then you subtract the 15 from the 15.80, and multiply the 0.80 by 100 to get 80 in numeric form.

The ROUND function requires the third parameter set to 1 to truncate the number. Otherwise, it would convert 15.80 into 16.00. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

For those that want to return the fractional value only... (i.e. without the decimal) SQLMenace posted  a great way to do this using PARSENAME from this Article: [How To Get Only Numbers After Decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418606/sql-how-do-i-get-only-the-numbers-after-the-decimal)

An IMPORTANT NOTE before use: If their is no decimal SELECT PARSENAME((22),2) will return NULL... And SELECT PARSENAME((22 ),1) will return only the whole number... This can easily be handled by COALESCE or checking for a zero modulus... but it may not be practical in all uses

```
SELECT PARSENAME((22.777),1) -- Returns ONLY The number after decimal
SELECT PARSENAME((22.777),2) -- Returns ONLY The whole number
```