# SQL - How do I get only the numbers after the decimal?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How do I get only the numbers after the decimal?

Example: `2.938` = `938`

Comment: Would -2.938 return 938 also?

Comment: Datatype? For bigint use `SELECT substr((2.938 % 1)::text,3)::bigint;`, else use text result.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

one way, works also for negative values

```
declare @1 decimal(4,3)
select @1 = 2.938

select PARSENAME(@1,1)
```

Comment: So what if the value is .042 it only returns 42 then?

Comment: no, it returns 042, both of these return 042--> SELECT PARSENAME(0.042,1), PARSENAME(.042,1)

Comment: If you want only 42, then select cast(PARSENAME(@1,1) as int)

Comment: Hmmm for some reason I'm getting 42
--Get remainder of day that was not worked
DECLARE @NotWorked DECIMAL(4,3)
SET @NotWorked = (@AllMins/@MinsInDay)
DECLARE @Remainder INT
SET @Remainder = PARSENAME(@NotWorked,1)

42 and 3.042

All Mins is INT MinsInDay is Decimal so 4380/1440

Comment: I don't know what your numbers are but try this  DECLARE @NotWorked DECIMAL(5,3) 
SET @NotWorked = (144/4380.0) 
select PARSENAME(@NotWorked,1)

it gives me 033

Comment: IS there a way to do this without the select I am actually try to give a @Remainder variable the value.... which in your can above would be the 033 or the number after the decimal

Comment: can't be an int since an int will dismiss the first 0, use varchar, example DECLARE @Remainder varchar(10)
DECLARE @NotWorked DECIMAL(5,3) 
SET @NotWorked = (144/4380.0) 

SELECT @Remainder = PARSENAME(@NotWorked,1)
select @Remainder -- see 033

Comment: This doesn't work if you pass it a float variable with zeros after the decimal. Example, `DECLARE @AMT FLOAT
SET @AMT = 3881.00
SELECT PARSENAME(@AMT, 1)`
It returns `3881`. Ok, so I see that you are specifically declaring the variable as decimal, but I think it should still be menioned.

Comment: It will not work if there is no fraction part. Example: select PARSENAME(1,1) returns 1. Which is wrong, it should ideally return either 0 or blank or null

Comment: The question is about numbers after the decimal..if you have a decimal with scale and precision you will never get this issue since it will then become 1.00 or something like that

Comment: This answer returns "Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric." IF the whole number is 2 digit and above. e.g. 10.1234.

Comment: ROUND can truncate as well since 2008. ROUND(Value, 0, 1)

Answer (score 150):

try this:

```
SELECT (num % 1)
```

Comment: Only seems to work if num if a DECIMAL.  Fails for me when num is a FLOAT.

Comment: In cases like SELECT (100.0001 % 1) the result shown contains '0.' part, that is 0.0001. But as per the question required part is '0001'

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2000 throws `Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Operand data type numeric is invalid for modulo operator.
Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Operand type clash: int is incompatible with void type`. Works nicely 2005 onwards.

Comment: Very nice! used also in C#, obviously without the SELECT, in fact this was too obvious! Hehe, but I guess sometimes is faster to find the answer than thinking a little bit, where we gonna stop!? Ha!

Answer (score 24):

You can use `FLOOR`:

```
select x, ABS(x) - FLOOR(ABS(x))
from (
    select 2.938 as x
) a
```

**Output:**

```
x                                       
-------- ----------
2.938    0.938
```

Or you can use `SUBSTRING`:

```
select x, SUBSTRING(cast(x as varchar(max)), charindex(cast(x as varchar(max)), '.') + 3, len(cast(x as varchar(max))))
from (
    select 2.938 as x
) a
```

Comment: Now try it for negative numbers: `SELECT -0.25 - FLOOR(-0.25)` gives 0.75.

Comment: Added [ABS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189800%28SQL.90%29.aspx) to handle negative numbers...

Comment: I like converting to a varchar and using the index of . to substr, works for any decimal places.

Answer (score 9):

More generalized approach may be to merge PARSENAME and % operator. (as answered in two of the answers above)

Results as per 1st approach above by SQLMenace

```
select PARSENAME(0.001,1)
```

Result: 001

```
select PARSENAME(0.0010,1)
```

Result: 0010

```
select PARSENAME(-0.001,1)
```

Result: 001

```
select PARSENAME(-1,1)
```

Result: -1  --> Should not return integer part

```
select PARSENAME(0,1)
```

Result: 0

```
select PARSENAME(1,1)
```

Result: 1  --> Should not return integer part

```
select PARSENAME(100.00,1)
```

Result: 00

Results as per 1st approach above by Pavel Morshenyuk
"0." is part of result in this case.

```
SELECT (100.0001 % 1)
```

Result: 0.0001

```
SELECT (100.0010 % 1)
```

Result: 0.0010

```
SELECT (0.0001 % 1)
```

Result: 0.0001

```
SELECT (0001 % 1)
```

Result: 0

```
SELECT (1 % 1)
```

Result: 0

```
SELECT (100 % 1)
```

Result: 0

Combining both:

```
SELECT PARSENAME((100.0001 % 1),1)
```

Result: 0001

```
SELECT PARSENAME((100.0010 % 1),1)
```

Result: 0010

```
SELECT PARSENAME((0.0001 % 1),1)
```

Result: 0001

```
SELECT PARSENAME((0001 % 1),1)
```

Result: 0

```
SELECT PARSENAME((1 % 1),1)
```

Result: 0

```
SELECT PARSENAME((100 % 1),1)
```

Result: 0

But still one issue which remains is the zero after the non zero numbers are part of the result (Example: 0.0010 -> 0010). May be one have to apply some other logic to remove that.

Comment: SQL 2022 helps you there:
TRIM(TRAILING '0' FROM PARSENAME('0.0010' % 1,1)) -- returns '001'

Answer (score 8):

The usual hack (which varies a bit in syntax) is

```
x - floor(x)
```

That's the fractional part.  To make into an integer, scale it.

```
(x - floor(x)) * 1000
```

Comment: hi think is best solution than the selected

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and solved with '%' operator:

```
select 12.54 % 1;
```

Comment: Could you explain what the `%` does?

Comment: % is the remainder of the euclidean division of one number by another. You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17524673/understanding-the-modulus-operator)

Answer (score 1):

Make it very simple by query:

```
select substr('123.123',instr('123.123','.')+1, length('123.123')) from dual;
```

Put your number or column name instead `123.122`

Comment: `from dual` is not SQL server compatible (unless you have table named `dual`, which is usually not the case). You can omit that part however :)

Answer (score 0):

If you know that you want the values to the thousandths, place, it's

```
SELECT (num - FLOOR(num)) * 1000 FROM table...;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select only decimal numbers use this WHERE clause:

```
    (CAST(RIGHT(Myfield, LEN( Myfield)-CHARINDEX('.',Myfield)+1 ) AS FLOAT)) <> 0
```

If you want a clear list you can sort by decimal/integer:

```
    CASE WHEN 0 = CAST(RIGHT(Myfield, LEN( Myfield)-CHARINDEX('.',Myfield)+1 ) AS FLOAT) THEN 'Integer' ELSE 'Decimal' END AS Type
```

Answer (score 0):

X - TRUNC(X), works for negatives too.

It would give you the decimal part of the number, as a double, not an integer.

Answer (score 0):

It's Gives You Only Decimal Values

Input :
select (18.45)%1

OutPut

0.45

Answer (score -2):

You can use RIGHT :

```
 select RIGHT(123.45,2) return => 45
```

Comment: This post is being automatically flagged as low quality because it is so short. Would you mind expanding it by adding some text to explain how this solves the problem?

Comment: Second parameter depends on how many decimals your data type has.

Answer (score -2):

CAST(RIGHT(MyField,  LEN( MyField)-CHARINDEX('.',MyField)+1 ) AS FLOAT)