# Get only decimal part in float number in SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have following number  in SQL Server 2008 : 5.4564556
I just want to get only 4564556 from 5.4564556
it would be better if i can get only 4 among 4564556 that is first digit of fractional part..

How can i do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get first four decimal parts by :

```
select SUBSTRING (PARSENAME(5.4564556,1), 1, 4)
```

Answer (score 12):

You can try in this way :

```
SELECT (5.4564556 % 1)
```

Comment: % operator in t-sql works for decimal(p,s), and it does not work for float.
`SELECT (5.4564556e0 % 1)` results in 
`Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 26
The data types float and int are incompatible in the modulo operator.`

Answer (score 11):

You can also use [FLOOR()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178531.aspx):

```
SELECT Value - FLOOR(Value)
```

In your case:

> 5.4564556 - 5 = 0.4564556

in case of negative value you can use [ABS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189800.aspx)

```
SELECT ABS(Value) - ABS(FLOOR(Value))
```

Comment: This is actually the best answer, because it is mathematically correct, and thus works for the set of all floats.

Answer (score 5):

To get all the numbers behind the '.', you can (ab)use [PARSENAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006.aspx)

```
select PARSENAME(5.4564556,1)
```

returns 4564556

Refer also to [SQL - How do I get only the numbers after the decimal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418606/sql-how-do-i-get-only-the-numbers-after-the-decimal)

Comment: @ghanshyam.mirani Note that PARSENAME returns a `NVARCHAR(256)`. I also didn't see the second part of your question `select LEFT(PARSENAME('5.4564556', 1), 1)` will return just the 4. You may need to cast it back to numeric type.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 select cast(5.4564556 % 1 * 10 as int)
```