# Modulo operator

Tags: javascript, jquery, modulo

9%4 = 1

1%4 and the answer is 1

2%4 and the answer is 2

Answer found. - CLOSED.

Comment: 1 % (any integer) === 1

Comment: Not really sure how it's possible to "get" that 9%4 == 1 but not being able to extrapolate that to the other cases.

Comment: OMG, this is embarassing. Brain fart, yes, I get it. Wish I could delete this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It has the correct  answer provided.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The meaning of Mod is that you take the remainder after doing the division.

1 fits zero times in 4, so the remainder is 1.

[Here](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) the wikipedia definition that explains in a little more detail:

> In mathematics the result of the modulo operation is the remainder of
>   an arithmetic division. As is well known, an arithmetic division of
>   two integers produces a quotient and a remainder.

Answer (score 3):

The modulo operator gives the **remainder** of the division. Other than `1`, anything divides `1` gives you `1` as the remainder.

i.e.,

```
  ______
4 | 1  ( 0
    0
  ------
    1
```

4 goes 0 times in 1. So putting a 0 in the division, will give you 1 as the remainder.

Answer (score 3):

First see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17525046/1848929
then

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171220131652/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/54363.html) says

> The "mod" operator in computer languages is simply the remainder. For
> example,
>
> ```
> 17 mod 3 = 2
> ```
>
> because
>
> ```
> 17 / 3 = 5 rem 2
> ```
>
> which in turn means
>
> ```
> 17 = 3 * 5 + 2
> ```
>
> There are some tricky issues when negative numbers are used, but that
> shouldn't ordinarily be necessary.
>
> In math (number theory), the term is used a little differently. The
> "modulus" is actually not the remainder, but the number you are
> dividing by; and "mod" is not an operator, but a label telling "in
> what sense two quantities are considered congruent, or equal." For
> example, we would say
>
> ```
> 17 = 11 (mod 3)
> ```
>
> (read as "17 is congruent to 11, modulo 3"), meaning that 17 and 11
> both leave the SAME remainder when divided by 3. You probably won't
> see this usage if you are only reading about programming, but it's
> worth being aware of if you look deeper into the math behind it.

Here are three references in archives:

Modulus Operator Problem
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171226013028/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/55771.html)

Mod
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20180121184122/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/55910.html)

Mod Function and Negative Numbers
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20180118003726/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/52343.html)

**Deeper:** http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Congruence.html

> If two numbers b and c have the property that their difference b-c is
> integrally divisible by a number  m (i.e., (b-c)/m is an integer),
> then b and c are said to be "congruent modulo m." The number m is
> called the modulus, and the statement "b is congruent to  c (modulo
> m)" is written mathematically as
>
> b=c (mod m).      (1) If b-c is not integrally divisible by m, then it
> is said that "b is not congruent to c (modulo m)," which is written
>
> b≢c (mod m).      (2) The explicit "(mod m)" is sometimes omitted when
> the modulus m is understood by context, so in such cases, care must be
> taken not to confuse the symbol = with the equivalence sign.
>
> The quantity b is sometimes called the "base," and the quantity c is
> called the residue or remainder. There are several types of residues.
> The common residue defined to be nonnegative and smaller than m, while
> the minimal residue is c or c-m, whichever is smaller in absolute
> value.
>
> CongruenceClockMinutes Congruence arithmetic is perhaps most familiar
> as a generalization of the arithmetic of the clock. Since there are 60
> minutes in an hour, "minute arithmetic" uses a modulus of m=60. If one
> starts at 40 minutes past the hour and then waits another 35 minutes,
> 40+35=15 (mod 60), so the current time would be 15 minutes past the
> (next) hour.
>
> CongruenceClockHours Similarly, "hour arithmetic" on a 12-hour clock
> uses a modulus of m=12, so 10 o'clock (a.m.) plus five hours gives
> 10+5=3 (mod 12), or 3 o'clock (p.m.)
>
> Congruences satisfy a number of important properties, and are
> extremely useful in many areas of number theory. Using congruences,
> simple divisibility tests to check whether a given number is divisible
> by another number can sometimes be derived. For example, if the sum of
> a number's digits is divisible by 3 (9), then the original number is
> divisible by 3 (9).
>
> Congruences also have their limitations. For example, if a=b and c=d
> (mod n), then it follows that a^x=b^x, but usually not that x^c=x^d or
> a^c=b^d. In addition, by "rolling over," congruences discard absolute
> information. For example, knowing the number of minutes past the hour
> is useful, but knowing the hour the minutes are past is often more
> useful still.
>
> Let a=a^' (mod m) and b=b^' (mod m), then important properties of
> congruences include the following, where => means "implies":
>
> 1. Equivalence: a=b (mod 0)=>a=b (which can be regarded as a definition).
> 2. Determination: either a=b (mod m) or a≢b (mod m).
> 3. Reflexivity: a=a (mod m).
> 4. Symmetry: a=b (mod m)=>b=a (mod m).
> 5. Transitivity: a=b (mod m) and b=c (mod m)=>a=c (mod m).
> 6. a+b=a^'+b^' (mod m).
> 7. a-b=a^'-b^' (mod m).
> 8. ab=a^'b^' (mod m).
> 9. a=b (mod m)=>ka=kb (mod m).
> 10. a=b (mod m)=>a^n=b^n (mod m).
> 11. a=b (mod m_1) and a=b (mod m_2)=>a=b (mod [m_1,m_2]), where [m_1,m_2] is the least common multiple.
> 12. ak=bk (mod m)=>a=b (mod m/((k,m))), where (k,m) is the greatest common divisor.
> 13. If a=b (mod m), then P(a)=P(b) (mod m), for P(x) a polynomial.
>
> Properties (6-8) can be proved simply by defining
>
> a =   a^'+rm   (3) b  =   b^'+sm,  (4) where r and s are integers. Then
>
> a+b   =   a^'+b^'+(r+s)m   (5) a-b    =   a^'-b^'+(r-s)m   (6)
> ab    =   a^'b^'+(a^'s+b^'r+rsm)m,     (7) so the properties are true.
>
> Congruences also apply to fractions. For example, note that
>
> 2×4=1    3×3=2    6×6=1 (mod 7),      (8) so
>
> 1/2=4    1/4=2    2/3=3    1/6=6 (mod 7).     (9) To find p/q (mod m)
> where (q,m)=1 (i.e., q and m are relatively prime), use an algorithm
> similar to the greedy algorithm. Let q_0=q and find
>
> p_0=[m/(q_0)],    (10) where [x] is the ceiling function, then compute
>
> q_1=q_0p_0 (mod m).   (11) Iterate until q_n=1, then
>
> p/q=pproduct_(i=0)^(n-1)p_i (mod m).      (12) This method always works
> for m prime, and sometimes even for m composite. However, for a
> composite m, the method can fail by reaching 0 (Conway and Guy 1996).
>
> Finding a fractional congruence is equivalent to solving a
> corresponding linear congruence equation
>
> ax=b (mod m).     (13) A fractional congruence of a unit fraction is
> known as a modular inverse. A fractional congruence can be found in
> the Wolfram Language using the following function:
>
> FractionalMod[r_Rational, m_Integer] := Mod[
> Numerator[r]PowerMod[Denominator[r], -1, m], m] or using the undocumented syntax PolynomialMod[r, m] for r an explicit rational
> number.

Answer (score 1):

The modulo operator gives you the remainder of the *integer* division. The integer result of `1/4` is 0, not 0.25.
So `1%4 = 1 - (1/4)*4 = 1 - 0*4 = 1 - 0 = 1` (and in general `n%m = n - (n/m)*m`)