# Repeat a JavaScript action every certain amount of clicks?

Tags: javascript

I've made a script which calls a function every 5 clicks on an element. What I'd like to do now is to repeat the action every 5 clicks, and not just call it only once. Is there any way to reset the variable count when the action is called?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var count=0;
$(".logo").click(function(){
    count+=1;
    if (count==5) {
        $( "body" ).toggleClass('easteregg');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: count=0 again is not an option?

Comment: serendipity has a good solution, but you could do something as simple as just setting `count=0` inside of your `if`.

Comment: if you want to support multiple elements, The count variable data can be stored with the element by jQuery.data. https://jsfiddle.net/xdfj01pr/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you don't have to reset it just do

```
if(count % 5 === 0){
    //your code here
}
```

This will be called every time the count is multiple of 5

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't fully understand how this works. Could you explain please? I'm a newbie in Javascript.

Comment: @Dimitris1337 sure. '%' means divide the `count` and return remainders. So in this code if you divide count by 5 and if the remainder is 0, it means the count is a multiple of 5, hence every 5 clicks.

Comment: So it should be something like this?

$(document).ready(function(){
    var count=0;
    $(".logo").click(function(){
        if (count % 5 === 0) {
            $( "body" ).toggleClass('easteregg');
        }
    });
});

Comment: if you want an in depth explanation of the mod % operator: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17524673/understanding-the-modulus-operator

Comment: @Dimitris1337 yes. The structure is hard to recognize in one line but if you just change the `count ==5` part to `count % 10 === 0`. It will fire every 10 counts. Also, `===` means do not force type coercion so if you want to be strict it is safer to use `===` than `==`

Answer (score 0):

Why not reset the counter after the action?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var count=0;
$(".logo").click(function(){
    count+=1;
    if (count==5) {
        $( "body" ).toggleClass('easteregg');
        count = 0;
    }
  });
});
```