# Understanding something more about the % Modulus operator

Tags: php, math, syntax, modulo, modulus

I am learning to work with some math like PHP query and just got to the modulo, I am not quite sure in what situations to use this because of something i stumbled on and yes I did already read one of the posts here about the modulo :
[Understanding The Modulus Operator %](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17524673/understanding-the-modulus-operator)

(This explanation is only for positive numbers since it depends on the language otherwise)

The quote above is in the top answer there. But if I focus on PHP only and i use the modulo like this:

```
$x = 8;
$y = 10;
$z = $x % $y;
echo $z; // this outputs 8 and I semi know why.

Calculation: (8/10) 0 //times does 10 fit in 8.
                    0 * 10 = 0 //So this is the number that has to be taken off of the 8
                    8 - 0 = 8 //<-- answer

Calculation 2: (3.2/2.4) 1 //times does this fit
                         1 * 2.4 = 2.4 //So this is the number that has to be taken off of the 3.2
                         3.2 - 2.4 = 0.8 // but returns 1?
```

So my question is why does this exactly happen. my guess would be that in the first phase it would get `8/10 = 0,8` but this doesn't happen. So can someone explain a bit about why this happens. I understand the modulo's basics like if I do `10 % 8 = 2` and I semi understand why it doesn't return something like this: `8 % 10 = -2`.

Also, is there a way to modify how the modulo works? so it would return a `-` value or a decimal value in the calculation? or would I need to use something else for this

Little shortened: why does this happen when I get a negative number in return and is there some other way or operator that can actually do the same and get in the negative numbers.

Comment: From the manual % - 'Remainder of $a divided by $b.', so 8/10 = 0 (only integer part), remainder = 8.

Comment: @NigelRen I did read it but is there a way for it to actually go to something like a double? or to the negative. becouse this isnt talked about in the manual. (as far as ive seen)

Comment: % is only for integers

Comment: As for -ve - from manual page `echo (-5 % 3)."\n";          // prints -2`

Comment: For floating point modulus, there is a function [fmod()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fmod.php)

Comment: @NigelRen hmm oke I hadnt thought about that yet but its still int then right?

Comment: @MarkBaker Ive read the page and yes idk how I didnt find this yet but this is somewhat wat I thought should have been possible with another function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modulus (%) only works for integers, so your calculation at the bottom of your example is correct...

> 8/10 = 0 ( integer only ), remainder = 8-(0*10) = 8.

If you instead had -ve 12 - `-12%10`...

> -12/10 = -1 (again integer only), remainder = -12 - (10*-1) = -2

For floats - you can use fmod(http://php.net/manual/en/function.fmod.php)

```
<?php
$x = 5.7;
$y = 1.3;
$r = fmod($x, $y);
// $r equals 0.5, because 4 * 1.3 + 0.5 = 5.7
```

(Example from manual)

Comment: Ah oke, thanks for this like @markbaker also said in the comments, this is what I thought should be doable but I hadnt found this function yet. maybe becouse I searched wrong or something but thanks this explains and helps a lot.