# Ruby loop through each element in an array n times

Tags: ruby

I've had a tough time finding an exact example of this.

If I have an array that contains 5 elements. E.g.

```
list = [5, 8, 10, 11, 15]
```

I would like to fetch what would be the 8th (for example) element of that array if it were to be looped. I don't want to just duplicate the array and fetch the 8th element because the `nth` element may change

Essentially the 8th element should be the number 10.

Any clean way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Math to the rescue

```
list[(8 % list.length) - 1]
```

[A link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17524673/understanding-the-modulus-operator) about this modulo operator that we love

Comment: The maths I needed! Thank you!

Comment: My pleasure Sir :)

Answer (score 2):

This should do:

```
def fetch_cycled_at_position(ary, num)
  ary[(num % ary.length) - 1]
end

ary = _
 => [5, 8, 10, 11, 15]

fetch_cycled_at_position(ary, 1)   # Fetch first element
 => 5

fetch_cycled_at_position(ary, 5)   # Fetch 5th element
 => 15

fetch_cycled_at_position(ary, 8)   # Fetch 8th element
 => 10
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`rotate`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-rotate):

```
[5, 8, 10, 11, 15].rotate(7).first
#=> 10
```

It's `7` because arrays are zero based.

Answer (score 1):

Just out of curiosity using [`Array#cycle`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-cycle):

```
[5, 8, 10, 11, 15].cycle.take(8).last
```

This is quite inefficient but fancy.

Answer (score 0):

I ran these in my irb to get the output,

```
irb(main):006:0> list = [5, 8, 10, 11, 15]
=> [5, 8, 10, 11, 15]

irb(main):007:0> list[(8 % list.length) - 1]
=> 10
```

hope it will help you.