# Get number value equal to 0 after exceeding 10

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code in html and javascript.

I want to increment the value displayed in `"#field"` to start over from 0 after it reaches the value of 10. ( instead of showing 11, it start over from 0 ).

And same as this condition, i want it to start over from 10 if the value gets below 0.

Thanks.

```js
 var value = 0;

/*Add function*/
function add() {
    value++;
    document.getElementById("field").innerHTML = value;
}

/*minus function*/
function minus() {
    value--;
    document.getElementById("field").innerHTML = value;
}

/*condition to start over from 0*/
if(value>10){
    value = 0;
    document.getElementById("field").innerHTML = value;
}
```

```html
<form>
        <input type="button" value="+" onclick="add();"/>
        <input type="button" value="-" onclick="minus();"/>
</form>
         <span id="field">0</span>
```

Comment: write that logic into a separate function and call it from `add` or `minus`

Comment: The problem is none of your functions are being called, you need to call them from somewhere

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: Yes, i did it, it works now, thanks @DanielA.White.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it by putting the condition in a separated function, and i had to call it from the 2 other functions.

```js
 var value = 0;

/*Add function*/
function add() {
    value++;
    document.getElementById("field").innerHTML = value;
    cdn();
}

/*minus function*/
function minus() {
    value--;
    document.getElementById("field").innerHTML = value;
    cdn();
}

/*condition to start over from 0*/
function cdn(){
    if(value>10){
        value = 0;
        document.getElementById("field").innerHTML = value;
    }

    if(value<0){
        value = 10;
        document.getElementById("field").innerHTML = value;
    }
}
```

```html
<form>
        <input type="button" value="+" onclick="add();"/>
        <input type="button" value="-" onclick="minus();"/>
</form>
         <span id="field">0</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a condition to verify the value of the value you are going to display. If the value is greater than 10 the reset the value to 0 or vice versa.

```js
var value = 0;

/*Add function*/
function add() {
  if(value==10){ //Condition 1
     value = -1;
  }
  value++;
  document.getElementById("field").innerHTML = value;
}

/*minus function*/
function minus() {
  if(value == 0){ //Condition 2
     value = 11;
  }
  value--;
  document.getElementById("field").innerHTML = value;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="button" value="+" onclick="add();"/>
    <input type="button" value="-" onclick="minus();"/>
</form>
<span id="field">0</span>
```

Comment: It's generally considered bad practice to simply give the code that solves someone's problem. See [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: I've added some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the value is more than or equal to 10 in your `add()` function and if so, set it to 0 and in your `minus()` function check if the value is less than or equal to 0, and if so, set it to 10.

```js
var value = 0;

/*Add function*/
function add() {
    if(value>=10){
      value = 0;
    } else {
    value++;
    }
    document.getElementById("field").innerHTML = value;
}

/*minus function*/
function minus() {
    if(value<=0){
       value = 10;
    } else {
    value--;
    }
    document.getElementById("field").innerHTML = value;
}

/*condition to start over from 0*/
if(value>10){
    value = 0;
    document.getElementById("field").innerHTML = value;
}
```

```html
<form>
        <input type="button" value="+" onclick="add();"/>
        <input type="button" value="-" onclick="minus();"/>
</form>
         <span id="field">0</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation**:

`add()` check if  value is less than 10, if `true` then increase the value. Once it will reach 10 then this condition block will be `false` and set `value = 0`

`minus()` check value is greater than 0, if `true` then decrease the value. Once it will reach 0 then this block will be `false` and set `value = 10`

Below is working code for `+` and `-` both buttons:

```js
var value = 0;

/*Add function*/
function add() {
  if (value < 10) {
    value++;
  } else {
    value = 0;
  }
  document.getElementById("field").innerHTML = value;
}

/*minus function*/
function minus() {
  if (value > 0) {
    value--;
  } else {
    value = 10;
  }
  document.getElementById("field").innerHTML = value;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="button" value="+" onclick="add();" />
  <input type="button" value="-" onclick="minus();" />
</form>
<span id="field">0</span>
```

Comment: The downvote here does seem unfair. I have upvoted to cancel it out.

Answer (score 0):

There's many ways to solve your issue. One way would be to as described in other answers and put the check as part of your increment (add) and decrement (minus) functions. Those are very good solutions, and should be used in practice because they are (1) effective, and (2) easy to understand.

However, this is a good chance to show the beauty of the modulus operator, `%`.
Modulus gives you the remainder of a division operation, so `5 % 3 = 2`, or 5 divided by 3 leaves you 2 left over. Here's a [great explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17524673/understanding-the-modulus-operator) that goes much further into depth, but as long as we understand it's just giving
us the remainder, we should be fine.

Modulo arithmetic is very helpful for looping through rings of values, such as your numbers 0-10, then back to 0. We'll see how soon, but first let's go through some of the other solutions. Suppose your counter started at 9, and you used
the increment function

```js
function add() { value++; };
```

After calling `add` twice, you would be at 11, just like you're seeing with your code.

So then you write the better function,

```
function add_checked() { 
    if (value < 10) {  // handle cases 0-9
        value++; 
    } else {
        value = 0;  // handle case 10
    }
};
```

This will solve your problem, but is kind of ugly. You can compress the if statement into one line using [ternary operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) (ie, one-line-ifs), like so:

```js
function add_checked_ternary() { value = (value < 10) ? (value + 1) : 0; };
```

This roughly translates to (1) check if `value` is less than 10, (2) if so, use the value `value + 1`, (3) otherwise use the value `0`, and (4) set `value` to whatever value you're using. Just as complicated.

Modulo lets us avoid this branching logic. Try the function

```
function add_limited() { value = (value + 1) % 11; };
```

When `value = 9`, `add_limited` will add 1, and then take the remainder modulo 11.
Since 10 can't be broken into 11 pieces, `10 % 11 = 10` and value will be 10. When
we call `add_limited` again, we add 1 and take the remainder again. 11 can be broken up exactly by 11, and so we have no remainder, `11 % 11 = 0`. This makes
value 0 instead of 11. All the values except for 10 get 1 added to them like normal, since they all stay less than 11. 10 loops back to 0, exactly as desired!

Now, even though we want to celebrate because we just did something *really* cool,  there is one more thing to think about: the negative side. Just like your increment function needs to wrap around when it goes above 10, your decrement function needs to wrap when it goes below 0. Let's start with `value = 1`, and skip to `minus_checked`.

```
function minus_checked() { 
    if (value > 0) {  // handle cases 1-10
        value--; 
    } else {
        value = 10;  // handle case 0
    }
};
```

When `value > 0`, it decrements as usual, and when `value = 0` it loops around. Let's try and make a modulus version (we leave `minus_checked_ternary` to the reader).

```js
function minus_limited_broken() { value = (value - 1) % 11; };
```

As you may have guessed, this version is broken, as when `value = 0`, `-1 % 11 = -1`. Unfortunately, javascript remainders don't convert negatives to positive like [google calculator does](https://www.google.com/search?q=-1+%25+11). But we can do it manually. Suppose we added 11 to our answer. Then 0 would become 10 instead of -1, but 1 would be 11 instead of 0, 2 would be 12 instead of 1, and so on until 10 would be 20 instead of 9. This isn't what we wanted, but notice that `10 % 11 = 10`, `11 % 11 = 0`, `12 % 11 = 1`, and so on until `20 % 11 = 9`. These are all the numbers we were looking for, so we can build our `minus_limited`:

```js
function minus_limited_v1() { value = (value - 1 + 11) % 11; };
```

or

```js
function minus_limited() { value = (value + 10) % 11; };
```

Who ever thought you could do subtraction by adding a number? Either way, modulo is a great way of creating wrap-around logic. One last thing, since we're only adding or subtracting 1, a better name for these functions would be increment and decrement, or `inc` and `dec`.