# Print two lines formatted under each other

Tags: java

I'm trying to format the output of a multiplication table where you can only have 5 numbers/integers on one line. I'm trying this using a printf method in a for loop but it's not working so far.

Code:

```
System.out.println("Which multiplication table do you want to print?: ");
int number = input.nextInt();
int calculation;
System.out.println("Multiplication table: " + number + ":");
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++ ) {
    calculation = number * i;
    System.out.printf("%-5s ", calculation);
}
```

My output:

```
3    6    9    12   15   18   21   24   27   30
```

Output I'm trying to get:

```
 3    6    9    12   15
 18   21   24   27   30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have multiple options to achieve this:
 1. Print a new empty line after the 5th iteraiton
 2. Add `"\n"` to mark end of line

1.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++ ) {
        calculation = number * i;
        if (i % 5 == 0) {
         System.out.println();
        }    
        System.out.printf("%-5s ", calculation);
}
```

2.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++ ) {
        calculation = number * i;
        if (i % 5 == 0) {
         System.out.printf("\n");
        }    
        System.out.printf("%-5s ", calculation);
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: One more question, what exactly is the "%" operator used for and when is it used for most of the time(examples please)?

Comment: Ah, sorry for not explaining that.

% is a _modulus_ operator in Java or modulo in Python (if im not mistaken) but they are exactly the same thing.

Essentially, it is a division operation but instead of returning the _quotient_  value it returns the remainder.

` x % 5 == 0 ` is an expression to check whether x is completely divisible by 5 as the remainder of that division operation is 0.

This is explained well here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17524673/understanding-the-modulus-operator

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Print a line breaker every 5 number:

```
calculation = number * i;
System.out.printf("%-5s ", calculation);
if (i % 5 == 0) {
   System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Print a newline after printing 5 elements:

```
if(i % 5 == 0)
   System.out.println();
```