# Explanation of % in SQL

Tags: sql

Could someone explain the difference between `%` in SQL?

I understand that `%` is a wildcard that allows you to query results with `LIKE` results, i.e. `a%` for words starting with **a**, but I am confused why the wildcard can be used as `% 2 = 0` to query for even numbers?

I saw an explanation that said `%` can be used as divide but I thought `/` was divide.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding The Modulus Operator %](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17524673/understanding-the-modulus-operator)

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (ANSI SQL has no such % usage...)

Answer (score 3):

`a % 2 = 0` here `%` as [Modulus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/modulo-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) arithmetic operator.

Syntax: `dividend % divisor`

Sample: `SELECT 15 % 2 AS Remainder` it will return the result as `1`

[**Demo on db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=edd22777a18633b04d24795cbdb5c1f1)

Answer (score 2):

When used outside of a string, the percentage symbol `%` is the [modulus operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/modulo-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), i.e. an operator which returns the remainder following division of the number preceding the operator by that following it.

Therefore, in your example, the expression `% 2 = 0` will be validated if the number preceding the percentage symbol is even, e.g. `12 % 2 = 0` will return `True`.

Whereas, when used in the pattern argument of a [like](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) expression, the percentage symbol represents a wildcard operator matching any sequence of characters (or no characters at all).

Answer (score 0):

Let's understand with an example:
I have created an Table name - 'c', which contain 2 attribute 'name' and 'num'.

when num%10 is calculated e.g. 55%10 -> gives 5.
If result is either 2 or 7 then it will not print that row
Elseif result (num%10) is NOT 2 or 7 then in this case it will print the row.

Now:

```
Select *from c where num%10 NOT In(2,7);
```

Check out Screenshot here :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sxld6.png)