# Is there a pythonic way to count the pairs that total up to whole minutes

Tags: python-3.x, counting

I'm trying to find pairs of songs with durations that add up to whole minutes. Example given song lengths [10, 50, 90, 30]. Calculate the total number of different pairs. I'm expecting a return of 2 since the first and second pair to 60 seconds and the third and fourth songs pair to 120. But I'm instead getting 1 pair.

```
def pair_with_target_sum(songs, k):
    n = len(songs)
    count = 0
    for i in range(0, n):
        for j in range(i + 1, n):
            if songs[i] + songs[j] == k:
                count += 1
    return count

def main():
    print(pair_with_target_sum([10, 50, 90, 30], 60))
    print(pair_with_target_sum([30, 20, 150, 100, 40], 60))

main()
```

Comment: your "is a whole minute" check is the trick here -- are you familiar with the procedure to check if a number is divisible by another number?

Comment: You are testing for the sum being 60, not "to whole minutes".

Comment: Check if `(songs[i] +songs[j]) % k == 0`...

Comment: Do you mean `sum(1 for c in itertools.combinations(songs, 2) if sum(c) % k == 0)` ?

Comment: What answer would you expect to get for `[10, 50, 50]` and for `[20, 40, 20, 40]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use the [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=combinations#itertools.combinations) in conjunction with the [modulo operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17524673/understanding-the-modulus-operator):

```
from itertools import combinations

def f(songs):
    count = 0
    for pair in combinations(songs, 2):
        if sum(pair) % 60 == 0:
            count += 1

    return count
```

Comment: The problem is that this one has `O(n^2)` complexity while it can be done in `O(n)`.

Answer (score 3):

There is different, and much simpler algorithm:

1. Create array with 60 buckets.
2. For each `value` in list run `counts[value % k] += 1`
3. Sum `min(counts[n], counts[(n + k) % k])` (the weird calculation instead of just using `k - n` is to handle special case `0`)

Comment: Beat me to it. I was going to suggest a`Counter` and just multiplying out the bucket for `n` and `(k - n)`

Comment: @MadPhysicist I assumed that @Levia wanted to use each "song" only once, that is why `min` call instead of multiplication. If they want number of possible combinations then the multiplication will be solution.

Comment: That makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your code work correctly with only changing a line and deleting the k parameter from your function definiton like this:

```
    def pair_with_target_sum(songs):
    n = len(songs)
    count = 0
    for i in range(0, n):
        for j in range(i + 1, n):
            if (songs[i] + songs[j]) % 60 == 0:
                count += 1
    return count

def main():
    print(pair_with_target_sum([10, 50, 90, 30]))
    print(pair_with_target_sum([30, 20, 150, 100, 40]))
    print(pair_with_target_sum([60, 60, 60]))

main()
```

This works correctly for me when I run the code with different inputs.