# What does the % mean in the player = (player % 2) ? 1 : 2;

Tags: c++, c

I have already surfing the internet for the use of % in the line but I can't seem to get a proper answer.

Comment: It's the modulus operator. A good answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/17525046/6400614

Comment: % represents the mod function/operator, i.e it gives you the remainder of the division. In more daily speech, %2 checks if a number is odd or even.

Comment: Note that you can do the same thing with `player = (player % 2) + 1`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice That's not true. Should be `((player + 1) % 2) + 1`

Comment: @amirali It could be `player = 2 - player % 2` or `player = 2 - (player & 1)` to avoid division.

Comment: @amirali after further analysis, I think the formula in the title is incorrect. Or at least it doesn't do what I expected which was to toggle `player` between `1` and `2`. Instead `player` always retains the same value: `(1%2)?1:2 => 1` and `(2%2)?1:2 => 2`. So this formula is a noop if player only has the values 1 and 2.

Answer (score 3):

**%** means the remainder operator.

Here, `player % 2` means the remainder after dividing variable `player` by `2`. It will be a value less than 2 and greater than or equal to 0.

If value is 0, the ternary operator `?:`, evaluates to false and if value is 1, then ternary operator evaluates to true.

Therefore if value of `player` is **even**, the `player` will be set to `2` and if the value of the player is **odd**, then it will be set to `1`.

Comment: It is the *remainder* operator.

Answer (score 0):

"%" is used to find the remainder.
In your case, the value of the player will divide by 2 and it will give the remainder.

Answer (score 0):

It is modulus operator i.e. calculates the remainder.

Let me break it and explain the whole expression:(assuming `player` is of int type)
 `player = (player % 2) ? 1 : 2;`

`player % 2` means `get remainder by dividing player by 2

`a?b:c` means if expression a ( note a is an expression) results to true or 1, then return b, else return c;

Now the whole inference:

If the remainder after dividing `player` by 2 is 0, assign 1 to `player`, else ( in which case remainder is 1), assign 2 to `player`.

Answer (score -1):

% Modulus Operator and remainder of after an integer division like 3%2=1
in your case it like

```
if(player%2==1){
 player=1;
}else{
 player=2;
}
```