# Modulus operator in java

Tags: java, modulus

I have some confusion on the modulus operator, modulus gives the remainder as the output. so why is it different for the below scenario?

```
public class ModulusTest{
       public static void main(String[] args) {
        
         System.out.println(" 7/10 : " + 7/10 );//0.7
         System.out.println(" 7%10 : " + 7%10 ); //0
         
         System.out.println(" 5/2 : " + 5/2 );//2
         System.out.println(" 5%2 : " + 5%2 );//1
}
}
```

The output i was expecting is as i kept in the comments on each line of the print statements in the above sample code.
output:

```
 7/10 : 0
 7%10 : 7
 5/2 : 2
 5%2 : 1
```

Comment: Integer division

Comment: Why would you expect the remainder of 7÷10 to be zero?

Comment: Good explanation here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17524673/understanding-the-modulus-operator

Comment: when we divide 7 with 10, the remainder will be zero and quotient is 0.7 (mathematically).

Comment: But you get 5/2 right -- why did you not think the quotient would be 2.5 and the remainder 0 there?  What difference do you perceive?  (I say 'perceive' because there is no difference - in both cases it's integer division with an integer remainder).

Comment: It's not the "modulus operator", it's the ["remainder operator"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3)  -- the 'remainder' for positive integers being pretty much how it was defined in primary school: 7 'goes into' 10 no times, with a remainder of 7.