# JavaScript is x divisible by y (x % y === 0)

Tags: javascript, math

can someone explain me this javascript syntax?

i know it returns if number is or isnt divisible by other by returning 0 or 1, but i dont understand the syntax. What is 12%2 for example?

use case example: `12%2 === 0 //true`

Comment: the % means `modulo` check google for that

Comment: [Duplicate](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+percentage+sign) of [Understanding The Modulus Operator %](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17524673/4642212). See [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9549780/4642212) and the documentation on MDN about [expressions and operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators) and [statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In computing, the modulo operation returns the remainder or signed remainder of a division, after one number is divided by another

This essentials means:

> What is the amount left over when dividing X by Y

Let's say you have 30 eggs and you only have 2 cartons with 12 spots for those eggs. Modulo is the amount of eggs left over that can't make a complete carton (6 in this case).

```
30 % 12 => 6
```

Some more examples:

```
5 % 2 => 1
6 % 2 => 0

20 % 5 => 0
21 % 5 => 1
22 % 5 => 2
23 % 5 => 3
24 % 5 => 4
25 % 5 => 0
```

Answer (score 1):

% is modulo, or called mod, the remainder when dividing.
For example, “5 % 3 = 2” which means 2 is the remainder when you divide 5 by 3.

Back to your question, 12 % 2 equals 0 is because you do not have any reminder left from the dividing.

Comment: Extra nerdsauce detail: In math, the remainder and the modulo aren't exactly the same, but I think this only matters when you're working with negative numbers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13683563/whats-the-difference-between-mod-and-remainder (JavaScript's `%` operator returns the remainder.)

Answer (score 0):

The % sign is for modulus, the remained when divided by. 3 % 2 = 1. So if something mod something else is zero then something is divisible by something else.