# How do the squre brackets evaluate in the below 'FizzBuzz' code?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```js
for(var i=1;i<100;i++){
   console.log(((['Fizz'][i%3] || '') + (['Buzz'][i%5] || '')) || i)
}
```

What does `['Fizz'][i%3]` stand for? Which ES version is this a part of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s original JS using syntax that was there before ECMA got involved.

`['Fizz']` is an array literal.

`['Fizz'][0]` is `'Fizz'`

`['Fizz'][1]` is `undefined` (etc)

`i%3` will give you the [remainder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) when you divide `i` by `3`

The output for this is:

```
1 %3 = 1 -> undefined
2 %3 = 2 -> undefined
3 %3 = 0 -> `Fizz`
1 %3 = 1 -> undefined
```

The `||` catches the 'undefined' and makes it `''`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
(['Fizz'][i%3] || '')
```

can be translated into

```js
let fizz = ['Fizz'];
let remainder = i % 3;
if(fizz[remainder] != undefined) {
   return fizz[remainder];
}
else {
   return '';
}
```

It instantiates an array with `['Fizz']` which then returns a "pointer" to the array object in memory. Then immediately is accessed by an array access brackets [] to get an index.

If the index exists it returns the value that corresponds to that index. in this case there is only the index 0, which contains the string value `'Fizz'`.

By using the modulus operator it returns the remainder if you were to keep subtracting the given value until you reach 0. Read more here: [Understanding The Modulus Operator %](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17524673/understanding-the-modulus-operator)

So every time `i` has the value that is a multiple of 3, the remainder will be 0, resulting in a hit on an existing index. When the remainder isn't 0, it returns `undefined`

`undefined` is a [falsy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839952/all-falsey-values-in-javascript) value which can then be bypassed with a default return value with the `||` OR operator. A "filled" string like `'Fizz'` is a truthy value, so that would return itself. The OR operator then returns an empty string.

The above snippet translated in longer code would become:

```js
for(var i=1;i<100;i++){
   let fizz = ['Fizz'];
   let buzz = ['Buzz'];
   let remainder_fizz = i % 3;
   let remainder_buzz = i % 5;
   let endstring = '';
   if(fizz[remainder_fizz] != undefined) {
      endstring += fizz[remainder_fizz];
   }
   else {
      endstring += '';
   }
   if(buzz[remainder_buzz] != undefined) {
      endstring += buzz[remainder_buzz];
   }
   else {
      endstring += '';
   }
   if(endstring.length == 0) {
      endstring = i;
   }
   console.log('long logic:',endstring, ' | short logic:',((['Fizz'][i%3] || '') + (['Buzz'][i%5] || '')) || i);
}
```