# Starting loop at exact time in the hour - 12 options

Tags: python

I want that loop start at 00 min and 2 sec or 05 min and 2 sec or 10 min and 2 sec, etc...

I have code which work but i feel so stupid because i think this can be solved in a better way. not the gopnik style.

How can I do it?

```
def time_now():
    now = datetime.now()
    current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    print("Current Time =", current_time)


while True:
         
        now = datetime.now()
        while ( now.minute == 0 and now.second == 2) \
           or ( now.minute == 5 and now.second == 2) \
               or ( now.minute == 10 and now.second == 2) \
                   or ( now.minute == 15 and now.second == 2) \
                       or ( now.minute == 20 and now.second == 2) \
                           or ( now.minute == 25 and now.second == 2) \
                               or ( now.minute == 35 and now.second == 2) \
                                   or ( now.minute == 40 and now.second == 2) \
                                       or ( now.minute == 45 and now.second == 2) \
                                           or ( now.minute == 50 and now.second == 2) \
                                               or ( now.minute == 55 and now.second == 2):
            
            time_now()
            #print("Current Time =", current_time)
            print('Something')
            time.sleep(300)
```

Comment: Use crontab: https://pypi.org/project/python-crontab/

Comment: all your values `minute` are divided by 5 so check only once `now.minutes % 5 == 0`. Or use `now.minutes in (0,5,10,...55)`. If you use `crontab` then you can use `*/5` to run when minute is divided by 5

Comment: @rdas problem is that `crontab` (and `python-crontab`) can't check seconds. But code could sleep 2 seconds.

Comment: tnx rdas! it work like charm. the simplest solutions are the best.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [modulus operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17524673/understanding-the-modulus-operator) as all your time instances are divisible by 5:

```
while ( now.minute % 5 == 0 and now.second == 2):
    print('Something')
    time.sleep(300)
```

Comment: This is how it should be done, simple and no extra libraries needed.

Answer (score 1):

Why the second while loop? Do you want to freeze the machine* for that second - then why apply the time.sleep? Looks kinda superfluous.

*note machine in this instance = cpu core, not the interpreter. I'm also not sure if it will sleep you for 300 seconds or 300.999 seconds if that distinction is important.

Anyway, the mod approach will work fine given your params here, but is rather fixed to params always being compatible with modulus. Could try

```
while True:
     
    now = datetime.now()
    if ( now.minute in [0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55] and now.second == 2):
        #Do something
        pass
```

Comment: Might as well use a tuple for the container: no need to modify it later (clearer on intention and saves a little ram).  Or even a set, since duplicate entries in a container used for membership tests make no sense, but I don't use sets as often as I should. @Wild_rasta this is the correct *general* solution to avoiding chained literal comparisons: this pattern is used a *lot* in python.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cronjobs` for this type of aproach. You can read and apply from [here](https://pypi.org/project/python-crontab/)
Edited: For managing seconds, you can simply use `sleep` function in the `cronjob`

Comment: problem is that `cornjob` don't check seconds. BTW: your link needs to login

Comment: I've updated the link with another one. You can use `sleep` to get the seconds you need