# SQL - Datatypes varchar and varchar are incompatible in the modulo operator

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]I have the following query that used to work but returns the error addressed on the title. The last line is indicated within the error.

```
UPDATE [dwh].[dbo].[opco_securty]
SET opco_general = REPLACE([dwh].[dbo].[opco_securty].opco_general, [MSTR_MD].[dbo].[v_OpcoGeneral_UserList].ABBREVIATION, '''')
FROM [dwh].[dbo].[opco_securty]
JOIN [MSTR_MD].[dbo].[v_OpcoGeneral_UserList]
ON [dbo].[opco_securty].opco_general LIKE CONCAT(''%'', [MSTR_MD].[dbo].[v_OpcoGeneral_UserList].ABBREVIATION, ''%'');
```

Comment: What's your dbms? could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: It is MS-SQL. I added an image to the post. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
ON [dbo].[opco_securty].opco_general LIKE CONCAT(''%'', [MSTR_MD].[dbo].[v_OpcoGeneral_UserList].ABBREVIATION, ''%'');
```

To this

```
ON [dbo].[opco_securty].opco_general LIKE CONCAT('%', [MSTR_MD].[dbo].[v_OpcoGeneral_UserList].ABBREVIATION, '%');
```

Because the goal is to concatinate the `%` character to the column. So that it creates a string that's usable by the `LIKE`.

But in MS Sql Server you escape a single quote with a single quote.

So the `''%''` is messing things up.
Because the % is seen as the [modulus operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17524673/4003419).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm confused that how that query was working successfully.

Comment: That's also a mystery to me. The modulus of a quote? Shouldn't have worked.

Comment: Well, depends on with what programming language you run it I guess.

Comment: Maybe the query was copied from a dynamic sql string?