# Alternating lines with Nested Loops

Tags: python, nested-loops

This is the exercise I need to complete:
Using nested loops, write some code that outputs the following:

```
##########
**********
##########
**********
##########
```

Following is all the code I have so far. I assume I need to combine these two loop functions to one but I'm struggling with it. I'm early on in my first class and any help with this would be appreciated!

```
for a in range (0, 5, 2): 
    for b in range(10):
        print("#", end = "")
    print("")
for a in range (1, 5, 2):
    for b in range(10):
        print("*", end = "")
    print("")
```

Comment: There is no picture ... Do not submit pictures.

Comment: what is the input ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do it. First you should check how many lines you need to output. *5*, so you need a loop doing something 5 times.

```
for i in range(5):
```

Now you need 2 loops to paste print the 2 line patterns (you already have them in your code)

```
 for b in range(10):
        print("#", end = "")
    print("")
```

and

```
for b in range(10):
        print("*", end = "")
    print("")
```

If you need to alternate between 2 values it's mostly the best to use the [Modulo Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17524673/understanding-the-modulus-operator).

So you can just switch between the 2 loops by `% 2`.

```
for i in range(5):
  if i % 2 == 0:
    for b in range(10):
        print("#", end = "")
    print("")
  else:
    for b in range(10):
        print("*", end = "")
    print("")
```

Comment: thank you for explaining it so clearly

Comment: @DylanEy Please consider marking the answer as accepted, to help others in the future.

Comment: okay will do sry just learnin

Answer (score 1):

Since no input is specified, only a fixed output:

```
for _ in '_':
    for _ in '_':
        print('''##########
**********
##########
**********
##########''')
```

And yes, if that was my homework exercise, I'd absolutely submit this.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to simply base the symbol on the row index, even or odd

```
nb_lines = 5
line_size = 10

for i in range(nb_lines):
    for _ in range(line_size):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            print("#", end="")
        else:
            print("*", end="")
    print()
```

---

But no need of nested loops

```
nb_lines = 5
line_size = 10

for i in range(nb_lines):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        print("#" * line_size)
    else:
        print("*" * line_size)
```

Comment: @DylanEy Now do it your self, without reference to this. Find several ways to do it. If you don't do it yourself, then you won't start learning until you leave collage. (assuming that you make it to the end: each term will get progressively harder, if you don't learn).

Answer (score 0):

```
def printStripes(row_length, number_of_rows):
    for _ in '_':
        print( "".join(
            [ "\n" if n%(row_length+1)==row_length else
              "#"  if (n//(row_length+1))%2==0 else
              "*"
              for n in range(number_of_rows*(row_length+1))
            ]
        ),end="")

printStripes(row_length=5,number_of_rows=8)
```

But don't tell your teacher that you got if from stackoverflow. (Thanks Kelly, for how to deal with the nested loop constraint.)

Comment: @KellyBundy fixed

Answer (score -1):

You can use this to get the result that you want

```
for i in range(0,5):
     print("*"*10)
     print("#"*10)
```

Comment: This won't work. It prints 10 lines.