# What does the %-sign in a function

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sign

I'm an absolute js novice and I'm self-tought which doesn't make it better.
I have the following function and want to understand what exactly the '% 5' does in it.

```
    $(function() {
      $(".carad" + new Date().getTime() % 5).css("display", "block");
    });
```

Comment: its the modulus operator https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder

Answer (score 0):

The **%** symbol means the "**modulo**" operator in JavaScript. This operator **returns the remainder after division is applied**. So here it would return the remainder of whatever Date().getTime() returned. For example, if the function returned a value of 23, the % would take the remainder of 23/5, which is 3.

Answer (score 0):

% sign simply returns the remainder for example
11%5 will return 1 as the answer.Hope you got your answer

Answer (score 0):

% in the programming world means mod which is the remainder of a division. for instance,  11 divided by 5 equals 2 and the remainder is 1. Here are some resources that teach mod in-depth:

[MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder)

[Geekbox](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/modulo-operator-in-c-cpp-with-examples/)

[Better Explained](https://betterexplained.com/articles/fun-with-modular-arithmetic/)

[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17524673/understanding-the-modulus-operator#:%7E:text=The%20Modulus%20is%20the%20remainder,and%209%20%25%204%20%3D%201%20.)

That is being said in the code you've provided you are creating a new date object and extracting the time out of it. So basically this code is trying to select a carad class with the remainder of the date. I have attached a code snippet that will help you understand the idea more.

```js
$(function() {
   $(".carad" + new Date().getTime() % 5).css("color", "red");
   $(".display-mod").text("the remainder is " + new Date().getTime() % 5);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="carad0">Hello world 0</h1>
<h1 class="carad1">Hello world 1</h1>
<h1 class="carad2">Hello world 2</h1>
<h1 class="carad3">Hello world 3</h1>
<h1 class="carad4">Hello world 4</h1>
<h1 class="carad5">Hello world 5</h1>
<h1 class="carad6">Hello world 6</h1>

<p class="display-mod"></p>
```

In short, this code selects a class with a random number.

**Note:** I've changed the applied styles to emphasize the idea

Comment: You helped me a lot to understand what a remainder is. But in your example - if I don't make a mistake - carad5 an 6 will never be red as there will be never a remainder 5 or 6 . Right?

Comment: In your case yes it will never be 5 or 6

Comment: I'm using this as a random function. But depending on the number of .carad in the list it needs obviously a different number to randomly assign the red color to all .carad in the list.
Maybe not the most clever idea to choose randomly a .carad from the list...

Comment: If you want to select a random carad class there are many more efficient and possible solutions you could use.