# MySQL: How can I get only decimal value from double type column?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE `sample` (
  `number` double NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


mysql> select * from sample
+-------------------+
| number            |
+-------------------+
| 1                 |
| 2                 |
| 3.5               |
| 4.5               |
| 0.1               |
+-------------------+
```

How can I get only the three decimal numbers?

```
+-------------------+
| number            |
+-------------------+
| 3.5               |
| 4.5               |
| 0.1               |
+-------------------+
```

Comment: With simple arithmetic

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860542/what-would-be-a-reliable-way-to-get-fractional-value-from-a-number

Comment: Thanks your comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one option with `cast`:

```
select * 
from sample
where cast(number as unsigned) <> number
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/152c9/1)

Comment: Or `floor(number) <> number`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a another way using `%` opertaor

```
select *
from Youtable
where `number` % 1 <> 0
```

- [**SQL FIDDEL DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1c27e/2)

Answer (score 0):

solution:

```
SELECT * FROM sample where number like '%.%';
```